# fullcalendar prevent repeated event loading with prev button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

With my fullcalendar I have a small problem in that if you are looking at the current month and want to go back to, say, January, you click on the prev button until you're there but each time you click it the request to load the events for that month is sent. So before January's events render it has to find June, May, April, etc, etc. It adds a fair bit of delay to the event loading. Is there any way to catch when there is a event loading request when the prev button is pressed and abort it?

Comment: You could override the click events on the DOM elements created, but how should your calendar know which month you'll stop at? Like in your example, how will the calendar know that you want to load January events?

Comment: Well what I want is to just be able to cancel the last request when another one is sent. Like in my example it would start loading July, but when I clicked to go to June it would abort the July request and start June's. Just a way to cancel any current request would work, but I only know how to abort a request when you have it as a variable and I don't know how to get the current request.

Comment: @Alexei Did you find a solution for this?